# Were mnemonics used to teach Classical Latin?

Tags: classical-latin, history

Latin has quite a complex grammar and many mnemonics have been used in the past as a memory aid. A famous example is the rhytmic "rosa rosa rosam" which is used to teach the first declension. It was immortalised in [a Jacques Brel song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v6rLLE48RL0) in 1962 and is still used today.

A cursory search reveals lists of mnemonics reproduced in textbooks as early as in [Alexandre de Villedieu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_of_Villedieu)'s [Doctrinale puerorum](http://www.olympiabookfair.com/antiquarian-books/d/alexandre-de-villedieu-doctrinale-puerorum-%5Bsouth-of-france%3F%5D-anno-domini-millesimo-ccc-lxxiiii-%5Bin-the-year-of-god-1374%5D/110508) (1199), but I can't find any mention of their use back when Latin was still a first language in much of the known world.

**Is there any record of mnemonics being used to teach Classical Latin when it was still a living language?**

If there is, have any survived into contemporary usage?

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call that a mnemonic, but I suspect the Romans didn't need mnemonics for such basic elements of grammar?

Comment: @Cerberus I'm not sure it qualifies either. It was listed as one on Wikipedia and it's the most well-known memory aid I know, hence why I used it as an example. The [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_mnemonics#Examples_and_analysis) has more complex examples but none that I've ever used. My first language has some well-known phrases and rhymes which were taught all the way through high school so I figured they'd have been used in ancient times as well.

Comment: @Cerberus, Quintilian wrote for 'foreigners' in the Roman Empire who needed to polish up their Latin for political careers and Legal work. That must have been a big clientèle.

Comment: I don't think so but we should ask Professor Dicky (Reading U) or Bruno Rochette (U de Liege). If they don't know, then no one else does.

Comment: Incidentally, I would like to draw your attention to a fantastic book by Professor Dicky, *Learning Latin the Ancient Way* (CUP, 2016). I couldn't put it down. You've been warned! :)

Answer (score 3):

The Answer that should be here, that is: one relating to a period when most serious conversation was in Latin, and not just in School, is Donatus. What survives of that is just a skeleton memorised as a framework.

**Alexander de Villedieu** wrote ***Doctrinale,*** a very popular Schoolbook, in  **1199** just as the thorough teaching of Classics was being replaced by crash courses with Anthologies replacing full texts of Ovid and Cicero. This v. short exract covers 1st Declension. *Nominativus* is here called *Rectus.* The metre is Dactylic Hexameter.
[image]

Image taken from **Archive** post of  *Seven Liberal Arts,* Abelson 1903

Comment: Interesting find but keep in mind that my question was mainly about the time when Latin was still a living language, not after its resurrection.

Comment: @Lilienthal Yes, only getting as far as the reviews of Professor Dicky's 2016 (Eastrn Empire) It looks as though the teaching used examples, quotes, proverbs, set pieces to show how grammar worked, This is the case with Quintilian(in Archive)(Western Empire), and Fecunda Ratis (in Archive) so, as i said, I think Donatus is your best bet, and that is a disappointment.

Comment: Could you clarify why you bring up Donatus (= Aelis Donatus' Ars Minor?)? And I assume that you're suggesting the Doctrinale as the first purposefully constructud mnemonic while no such memory devices are known from older times (which would answer the bolded question)?